# How to draw a Google Chart with temperature and humidity data from XML file?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml, arduino

I have the following xml file:

```
<data>
<temp>21</temp>
<humidity>17</humidity>
<analog>670</analog>
<analog>908</analog>
<analog>628</analog>
<analog>909</analog>
<LED>off</LED>
<LED>off</LED>
<LED>off</LED>
<LED>off</LED>
<OSSZRELE>off</OSSZRELE>
</data>
```

this xml file generates in a webserver every second, I would like to draw a chart from temp and humidity data with Google Charts. Can somebody tell me how to do that with line chart? sorry for my English. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Apps Script to read the data in a Google Spreadsheet and then make the chart.